# How to update Core Data assigned to indexpath in Custom cell via button

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an app of type "to do list" where I want to check my item on the list with custom button checkmark. Structure of app looks like that: main list uses UITableViewController which has custom TableViewCell with UIButton "checkmarkButton" and Label "cellLabel". Their values are saved to core data after creating, with checkmarkButton default state as false, and are assigned to a cell in cellForRowAtindexPath using value(forKeyPath:). In TableViewCell class I have a checkmarkBtnTapped function which changes displayed image for a button (check/uncheck), tint this image to a specified color, and update button "state" as bool in CoreData attribute for its key path, fetch CoreData and reloadTableView. Some functions that use my list array and other stuff from core data, or table view come from UITableViewController so I implemented delegate for them.

The problem is when I tap the checkmarkButton and it uses updateBtnState new row is created with changed state (i.e. i have tapped row with button in state "false", my actual row with label is still on "false" and new row is added with empty label and button in state "true") i guess this is due to updateBtnState() method that reference only to managedObjectContext and not to indexPath. But when I try to reference item as a point of indexPath and not NSManagedObject i cannot pass this function to TableViewCell class due to IndexPath parameter. Below in TableViewController.swift i left updateBtnState2() that i think could solve my problem but is unusable in TableViewCell checkmarkBtnTapped() function

[image: CoreData model]

[image: TableView after adding items to list]

[image: TableView after checking button of existing items]

**TableViewController.swift**

import UIKit
import CoreData

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, ButtonSelectionDelegate {

```
var list: [NSManagedObject] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "List"

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))

        let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil)
       self.tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")   
    }

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    fetch()    
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.default
}

func save(name: String, state: Bool) {
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity =
        NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Item", in: managedObjectContext)!
    let Item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)

    Item.setValue(name, forKeyPath: "name")
    Item.setValue(state, forKeyPath: "isChecked")
    do{
        try managedObjectContext.save()
        list.append(Item)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}

func fetch(){
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }
    let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Item")
    do{
        list = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}

func updateBtnState(state: Bool){

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Item", in: managedObjectContext)!
    let Item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)

    Item.setValue(state, forKeyPath: "isChecked")

    do{
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Couldnt update. \(error)")
    }
}

func updateBtnState2(indexPath: IndexPath, state: Bool){

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let item = list[indexPath.row]

    item.setValue(state, forKeyPath: "isChecked")

    do{
        try managedObjectContext.save()
        list[indexPath.row] = item
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Couldnt update. \(error)")
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return(list.count)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        let item = list[indexPath.row]
        cell.selectionDelegate = self
        cell.cellLabel.text = item.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String
        cell.checkmarkButton.isSelected = item.value(forKeyPath: "isChecked") as! Bool
        return cell
    }

func updateTableView(){
    tableView.reloadData()
}

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

@objc func addTapped(){

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Name", message: "Add a new name", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) {
            [unowned self] action in
            guard let textField = alert.textFields?.first,
                let nameToSave = textField.text else {
                    return
            }
            self.save(name: nameToSave, state: false)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default)
        alert.addTextField()
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        alert.addAction(saveAction)
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
```

**TableViewCell.swift**

```
import UIKit


protocol ButtonSelectionDelegate: class {
    func fetch()
    func updateTableView()
    func updateBtnState(state: Bool)
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell  {
    weak var selectionDelegate: ButtonSelectionDelegate!
    @IBOutlet var checkmarkButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var cellLabel: UILabel!
    @IBAction func checkmarkBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
      sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        if sender.isSelected {
            selectionDelegate?.updateBtnState(state: true)
            let image: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "done_icon.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
            checkmarkButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
            checkmarkButton.tintColor = UIColor( red: CGFloat(21/255.0), green: CGFloat(126/255.0), blue: CGFloat(251/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
            selectionDelegate?.fetch()
           selectionDelegate?.updateTableView()
            print("checkmarkButton pressed to done")
        } else {
            selectionDelegate?.updateBtnState(state: false)
            let image: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "undone_icon.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
            checkmarkButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
            checkmarkButton.tintColor = UIColor.gray
            selectionDelegate?.fetch()
            selectionDelegate?.updateTableView()
            print("checkmarkButton pressed to undone")
        }
    }

     override func layoutSubviews() {
     super.layoutSubviews()
    let image: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "undone_icon.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
     checkmarkButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
     checkmarkButton.tintColor = UIColor.gray
     } 

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
}

extension UIButton {
    func hasImage(named imageName: String, for state:     UIControlState) -> Bool {
        guard let buttonImage = image(for: state), let namedImage = UIImage(named: imageName) else {
            return false
        }
        return UIImagePNGRepresentation(buttonImage) == UIImagePNGRepresentation(namedImage)
    }
}
```

Comment: don't allow empty value to add in Core data, your current code allows user to enter empty data that blank text added bottom rows

Answer (score 0):

The best way to work with table and collection view cells is to have the cell take care of all configuration of its UI. To do this you pass the data in to the cell and it then puts the right data in the right data formatted as desired. You already have a custom `UITableViewCell` so this will be pretty easy to do…

```
// Make the to-do item's property names into strings so you can't mistype them later.
// The other option would be to create the subclass of NSManagedObject so the properties are directly accessible.
let isChecked = "isChecked"
let name = "name"

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell  {
    // Add a property to hold the actual to-do item
     var item: NSManagedObject? {
         didSet {
             updateCell()
        }
    }
    // Make all outlets private so you aren't tempted to touch them from outside
    @IBOutlet private var checkmarkButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet private var cellLabel: UILabel!
    // Create both images once for each cell rather than every time the image changes
     let doneImage = UIImage(named: "done_icon.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
     let notDoneImage = UIImage(named: "undone_icon.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

     let doneColor = UIColor( red: CGFloat(21/255.0), green: CGFloat(126/255.0), blue: CGFloat(251/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
     let notDoneColor = UIColor.gray

     private func updateCell() {
         guard let item = item else { return }
         cellLabel?.text = item.value(forKeyPath: name) as? String
         checkmarksButton?.isSelected = item.value(forKeyPath: isChecked) as! Bool
    }

    @IBAction private func checkmarkBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // Safely unwrap the to-do item
         guard let item = item else { return }
         sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
         let selected = sender.isSelected
         item.setValue(selected, forKeyPath: "isChecked")
         checkmarkButton.setImage(selected ? doneImage : notDoneImage, for: .normal)
         checkmarkButton.tintColor = selected ? doneColor : notDoneColor
         print("checkmarkButton pressed to \(selected ? "done" : "undone")")
    }

     …
}
```

This way the cell can update the managed object directly rather than trying to reconnect to it through the view controller.

Also, the code in `layoutSubviews` shouldn't really be needed but if it is `awakeFromNib` is the better place to put it.

Once you cell is done you can get rid of those update button functions and change `cellForRowAt` to…

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    …

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
         let item = list[indexPath.row]
         cell.item = item
         return cell
    }

    …
}
```

Comment: Note: I didn't use a compiler for the above code so there might be a couple mistakes in it, the idea is sound though.

Comment: Thanks, it's kinda working... besides it is not saving to core data button state(or it is but its not loading?), and after implementing moveRowAt method button icon stays at row where it was tapped, i can move row to another position, and cellLabel will stay at new position, but icon stays at oryginal row with different cellLabel that took place of old label after moving row. It also save deletion of row(more acuratelly of cellLabel, because if on the deleted row was selected button its state stays at this row as i written above).

Comment: I also had to place code from layoutSubview, because without it buttons were loading without any icon

Comment: So in addition to the cell switching between checked and un-checked you also want checked cells to move to a specific part of the list? If so try setting sort descriptors on the fetch request and use `NSFetchedResultsController` to handle the request. Then you can implement `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` and respond to the addition, deletion, movement, and updates of/to the entities. You should be able to find numerous tutorials for `NSFetchedResultsController` with your favorite search engine that can provide much more detail than any answer here can.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to do this, but currently even without rearranging rows button state is not being saved after restarting the app, i have fetch() call in viewWillAppear()

Comment: i've setted up a print() when new value is setted in updateCell() and it turns out that updateCell() is not being called when button is tapped via didSet, but is called when the row is deleted or when is fetched after app launch, then still isChanged value is changed to 1 so to "true" but this doesnt affect image of the button. How can i solve this?

Comment: ...ok isChanged value was equal 1 because i've setted initial value of isChanged to "true", but after changing it to "false" it still stays with that value, and nothing changes this initial value

Comment: `didSet` on `item` is for when the item is first assigned to the cell (for configuring the UI properly), it has nothing to do with the checkmark button. That should still be hooked up to trigger `checkmarkBtnTapped`. You may need to save the context in `checkmarkBtnTapped` unless you already have some other periodic save implemented.